# Flowplayer playlist setPlaylist(array) does not change playlist dynamically

Tags: javascript, flowplayer

On the page a have a flowplayer which play videos by provided tag (just a name of video category) using playlist plugin. And I have section “Suggested videos”. When I click on suggested video, I want to reload playlist using newly selected video tag. I tried use setPlaylist(array) as described in documentation https://flowplayer.org/docs/playlist.html#methods:

```
var player = flowplayer(); 
player.setPlaylist(this.playlist);
```

but it's not working.

Full player method code:

```
updatePlayer() {
     if(document.getElementById('flow').innerHTML === "") {

                        var player = flowplayer(document.getElementById("flow"), {
                            autoplay: true,
                            playlist: this.playlist,
                            loop: true
                        });
                        // here I add all player events what I need
                   } else {
                        console.log('player updated');
                        var player = flowplayer();

                        player.unload();
                        //update flowplayer playlist
                        player.setPlaylist(this.playlist);
                    }
    }
```

When the player is initialized and I click to suggested videos console.log() shows me message and player.unload() works, but setPlaylist() doesn't.

The only solution what can help its to use shutdown() method, which destroys all player instances, events and so on. But it is an ugly solution I think, previous I used JW player where you can easily update playlist dynamically. 
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is  `player.setPlaylist(this.playlist).play(0);`

Comment: I got the answer in  [official forum](https://flowplayer.org/forum/#!/@flowplayer:338761). Not sure b-z a provided link to `play` method in the answer  is not working, but I think we need set a state a player to `play` and set a index of playlist item from waht you want to start new playlist